# Going from DRMs to Indirect Mechanisms

Tags: reference-request, mechanism-design

I have recently started studying mechanism design (after having taken a basic graduate micro course) through Borgers' 'Introduction to the theory of mechanism design'.

I was wondering if people are aware of any books/papers that explore how to actually construct real-world indirect mechanisms that implement the optimal allocations/transfer rules that are characterized throughout the text. So far I have not detected some methodology underlying going from drms to indirect mechanisms, just scattered examples. Am I missing something here?

Comment: There is no one-fits-all solution here. The "best" indirect mechanism always depends on the setting at hand. You often start looking for mechanisms in which the true type report is a weakly dominant strategy. For instance, a second-price auction with bid-subsidies and individual reserve prices.

Comment: Perhaps [market design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Market_design) is what you're looking for? [Al Roth's page](https://web.stanford.edu/~alroth/) is a good place to start.